# TSQL : Return the results of two functions in a single select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, function, csv

Is it possible to return the result of two function calls in a select statement?

I have the below TSQL snipped that accepts two csv string which I want to insert into a temp table in order. `dbo.Split` takes the string and returns a table of values.

**Snippet**

```
DECLARE @MeasureCategoryIDs as nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @SnapshotIDs as nvarchar(100)

    SET @MeasureCategoryIDs = '1,2,3'
    SET @SnapshotIDs = '9,8,7'

    CREATE TABLE #tmpMeasureCats
    (
        MeasureCatID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        SnapshotID int NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmpMeasureCats
        SELECT value FROM dbo.Split(',',@MeasureCategoryIDs), value FROM dbo.Split(',',@SnapshotIDs)

    DROP TABLE #tmpMeasureCats
```

**Split**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] 
   (  @Delimiter varchar(5), 
      @List      varchar(8000)
   ) 
   RETURNS @TableOfValues table 
      (  RowID   smallint IDENTITY(1,1), 
         [Value] varchar(50) 
      ) 
AS 
   BEGIN

      DECLARE @LenString int 

      WHILE len( @List ) > 0 
         BEGIN 

            SELECT @LenString = 
               (CASE charindex( @Delimiter, @List ) 
                   WHEN 0 THEN len( @List ) 
                   ELSE ( charindex( @Delimiter, @List ) -1 )
                END
               ) 

            INSERT INTO @TableOfValues 
               SELECT substring( @List, 1, @LenString )

            SELECT @List = 
               (CASE ( len( @List ) - @LenString ) 
                   WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                   ELSE right( @List, len( @List ) - @LenString - 1 ) 
                END
               ) 
         END

      RETURN 

   END
```

**Results from calling the split function on both csv strings**

[image]

When I run the snippet above I get the below error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

What I am looking for is as below

```
Col1     Col2
1        9
2        8
3        7
```

Is there another way to term the Select statement to return the two values for the Insert?

Comment: which values do you want in your table ?

Comment: what do you want that will be occur in case that langth not equal. for example '1,2,3' and '1,2'

Comment: @David, I have already pre-validated that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO #tmpMeasureCats(MeasureCatID, SnapshotID)
select t1.value, t2.value
from
(SELECT value, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn FROM dbo.Split(',',@MeasureCategoryIDs)) t1
join
(SELECT value, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn FROM dbo.Split(',',@SnapshotIDs)) t2
on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your functions are working as expected

```
INTO #tmpMeasureCats
SELECT 
    A.value as 'MeasureCat', 
    B.value as 'Snapshot'
FROM 
    dbo.Split(',',@MeasureCategoryIDs) A, 
    dbo.Split(',',@SnapshotIDs) B
```

Comment: Does not work as it creates a value for the first column for each of the second columns. EG 1,9 ; 1,8 ; 1,7 ;2,9 etc

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO #tmpMeasureCats
     SELECT value FROM dbo.Split(',',@MeasureCategoryIDs)
INSERT INTO #tmpMeasureCats
SELECT value FROM dbo.Split(',',@SnapshotIDs)
```